# how to stick a footer without covering the content?

Tags: html, css

```
div.footer {

    position: absolute;
    background: silver;
    height: 200px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I've sticked my footer to the bottom of the page, but if the content is long it is covered by this footer, how to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a margin to the bottom of the content area the same as the height of the footer.
Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X3B4c/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content">
    <!-- many lines -->
</div>
<div id="footer">&copy; 2014 SomeCompany Inc.</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#content {
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px; /*same as #footer's height*/
    background: #555;
}
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that maybe because you have position set to absolute.
Could you link the full coding of html and css?
Here is something which might help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<header></header>
<section></section>
<nav></nav>
<aside></aside>
<footer></footer>

</body>
```

Just think of this as a 3D object and your footer is coming infront of your elements or body. Use this structure. :)

Answer (score 0):

one thing You can do is rather then using **position:absolute** use **position:fixed** this will stick at that points.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

change the `position: absolute` to `position: fixed`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/SjKN6/)**

```
div.footer {
    position: fixed;
    background: silver;
    height: 200px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9N5yc/)**

**css**

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div.footer {

    position: fixed;
    background: silver;
    height: 200px;
    bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the z—index property
`img.  {position:absolute;  top:0;  z-indez:-1;}`